# CakePHP: calling an action with argument from another action within controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have an action, `print_pdf()` that prints a PDF, and I'd like to keep this action and its view for only printing PDFs because what gets rendered for this action is what gets printed in the PDF file. So, I've created an action that creates a user interface for printing documents via the action `bleh()`.

```
public function bleh() {
     $this->print_pdf($arg);   // this doesn't work
}


public function print_pdf($arg) {
     $this->render();
}
```

However, since `print_pdf()` is an action, it requires the form of `../controller/print>pdf/arg` for the action to be executed properly. Is there another way to accomplish this without using `requestAction` or `redirect`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the form submission data from `bleh()` persists in `print_pdf()`, so it doesn't look like I need an argument to pass to `print_pdf()`.

```
public function bleh() {
     // form submission is made

     $this->print_pdf();   // no argument
}

public function print_pdf() {

    if (check form submission) {
        $arg = $this->data[previous_form_data];

        // some stuff

        $this->render();
    }
}
```

This works well, but I'd still like to know if there's a way similar to my original approach.

Comment: Are you referring to the `$arg` I left in `print_pdf($arg)`? Because that was a typo, and I fixed that just now. And yes, this is working. Also, this is juts some pseudocode..

Comment: That's why this is a pseudocode. In `pdf_print()`, I am doing `if (isset($this->data['Model']['arg']))` to check for the previous form submission and `$arg = $this->data['Model']['arg']`.

Comment: Also, about `print_pdf` being public.. if I make it `protected`, it can't be called at all. How can I make it "non-public" and make it work in this framework? As of now, if you just go to `controller_name/print_pdf`, nothing shows since no form submission was made..

Comment: being protected doesn't stop you calling it as `$this->print_pdf();` it only prevents the url `/controllername/print_pdf` from being accessible (since the dispatcher can't access the protected function on a different object).